# cannot run CUDA Python examples

Tags: python, cuda

I am trying to run CUDA Python examples from https://github.com/NVIDIA/cuda-python.

I have installed CUDA on my system (Ubuntu 18.04):

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2022 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Mon_Oct_24_19:12:58_PDT_2022
Cuda compilation tools, release 12.0, V12.0.76
Build cuda_12.0.r12.0/compiler.31968024_0
```

and have the following packages installed in my virtual env.

```
Package          Version
---------------- -------
cupy-cuda12x     12.3.0
Cython           3.0.8
fastrlock        0.8.2
iniconfig        2.0.0
numpy            1.26.3
packaging        23.2
pip              23.3.2
pluggy           1.3.0
py-cpuinfo       9.0.0
pyclibrary       0.2.1
pyparsing        3.1.1
pytest           7.4.4
pytest-benchmark 4.0.0
setuptools       69.0.3
```

When runing :

```
python3 -m pytest
```

in my virtual env, I get (below is the first error):

```
================================================================= ERRORS ==================================================================
_________________________________________ ERROR collecting cuda/benchmarks/test_launch_latency.py _________________________________________
ImportError while importing test module '/home/myl/Desktop/cuda-python-main/cuda/benchmarks/test_launch_latency.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
/usr/local/lib/python3.11/importlib/__init__.py:126: in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
cuda/benchmarks/test_launch_latency.py:9: in <module>
    from cuda import cuda
E   ImportError: cannot import name 'cuda' from 'cuda' (/home/myl/Desktop/cuda-python-main/cuda/__init__.py)
```

I tried installing `cupy-cuda` instead of `cupy-cuda12x` but it did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You installed `cupy-cuda`, but the repo you linked to is for `cuda-python`.
Try installing that with `pip install cuda-python`.